# Java threads run interlaced

Tags: java, multithreading

I hope to write a program that runs the stream as follows

```
+Thread 1,2 run together method run of the Runnable
    +If thread 1 runs successfully 
        + thread 2 pause        
        + thread 1 run successfully methodReadResults
            +thread2,thread3 run together
                + thread2 keep running
                + thread 3 run method run of the Runnable
```

=>same until the end.It resembles the pool type of threads that run when free and pauses when a thread is successful.
The basic code I am trying to execute.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Person person = new Person("Name " + i);
        Thread thread = new Thread(person);
        thread.start();

        person.methodReadResults();
    }
}

private static class Person implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Integer> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            results.add(i);
        }
    }

    private void methodReadResults() {
        //Read results
        System.out.println(results.size());
    }
```

If Executors or a pre-built thread can execute my type program with the easier way,please tell me.Thank you

Comment: why is `Person` static?

Comment: Because all the classes I put in a Main class, I can not initialize it unless I put the static in the main method